# Is there any workaround for the permission denied (publickey) error in google cloud?

Tags: linux, ssh, gcloud

I am currently doing the Build and Secure Networks in Google Cloud: Challenge Lab from Google Cloud Skills Boost. I finished challenge number 1-5, but got stuck in challenge number 6:

> In the Compute Engine instances page, click the SSH button for the bastion host. Once connected, SSH to juice-shop.

After SSH to bastion, I typed `ssh (IP address of juice-shop)`, but it results in `Permission denied (publickey).` error. I tried typing -v after the SSH command, and this is what shows up after executing:

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u7, OpenSSL 1.0.2u  20 Dec 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.11.2 [192.168.11.2] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/student-04-e657ce74df3d/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/student-04-e657ce74df3d/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/student-04-e657ce74df3d/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/student-04-e657ce74df3d/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/student-04-e657ce74df3d/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/student-04-e657ce74df3d/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/student-04-e657ce74df3d/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/student-04-e657ce74df3d/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u7 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.11.2:22 as 'student-04-e657ce74df3d'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:T6OeQTHDWFMJTDZ8K02/glob0my9gLLdqH4IOJFIzwc
debug1: Host '192.168.11.2' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/student-04-e657ce74df3d/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_fetch_identitylist: invalid format
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/student-04-e657ce74df3d/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/student-04-e657ce74df3d/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/student-04-e657ce74df3d/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/student-04-e657ce74df3d/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

After checking the `.ssh` folder, the only file in there is `known_hosts`, and the content is `|1|Ufd+u5OJlKnZGrn7IXI2Bu/4XUs=|U1BWwkP97chmDwk/6E71T7UvKHM= ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBJuxpHVNlFCmVFiHVuq+wKn/WlMs9thpNHT2M8rExeTYeEbjq//qlHLkZFMyEXFKaLAaMVHCG1O5ohR+KRuugXU=`

Has the same problem occurred to anyone else, or does anybody have any solution to this problem? Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Please add the link to the challenge to save us from having to try to find it

Comment: The error appears to be that the host that you're using as the ssh client does not have the private key for the target. Unless there's a bug in the tutorial, there are 2 other possibilities; you're using the wrong client (and the correct one has the private key); you missed a step in copying (or perhaps generating) the private key.

Comment: @DazWilkin's comment is spot on.  I would add that since you have to "cross" a bastion host, you have to either copy your identity file on it, or setup an ssh agent.  That agent will  "configure" the bastion host with your identity so the ssh to juice-shop will let you in.

Comment: For security reasons debugging this problem on the client side is not productive because the server does not indicate the real reason. You need to log in to the VM and look at the OpenSSH logs to know the actual reason why.

Comment: Thank you DazWilkin, Nic3500 and John Hanley for the replies. The SSH keys are preconfigured, so after clicking the SSH button from the console, the keys are automatically copied. Moreover, I'm not savvy enough to setup an SSH agent or look at the OpenSSH logs. Luckily the problem did not occur when I tried the challenge again today. I think it was some kind of bug that made the SSH keys missing from the bastion host yesterday.

Answer (score 9):

Run this command in bastion SSH.

gcloud compute ssh juice-shop --internal-ip

after this keep empty in passphrase and press enter two times and press y in y/n.
and check your progress.

Comment: This works (upvoted!) though I still don't perfectly understand what is going on. I think that it is a mixture of two things: (1) the `--internal-ip` ensures that the traffic is internal (the challenge had us configure this to be allowed) rather than to the hostname's external IP. In theory we could `ssh <juice-shop internal-ip>` to replicate that ... but we also need (2) the SSH Agent Forwarding built into `gcloud compute ssh` which means that we don't have to copy keys or run an ssh-agent as mentioned by @Nic3500 in the comments above.

Comment: Ha! And it also depends on how you arrived on `bastion`. If you came in from the Google Console's "SSH" button then your keys get copied with you as a convenience and `ssh` just works. But if you came in from the cloud console via an IAP tunnel (to simulate 'an external connection' in the spirit of the problem - then you don't bring keys with you, and need to lean on `gcloud compute ssh` or else configure things yourself.